# nuxt hot-reload not working inside virtual machine

Tags: vue.js, vagrant, nuxt.js, homestead

I have a nuxt.js application running inside a virtual machine (homestead, to be precise), but when I edit my files outside the virtual machine, hot-reload is not working. If I SSH into the machine and edit a file there, it works fine. Any ideas?

I also have to add the port to the URL to get to the application. Does anyone have any ideas on how to remove it so that I no longer have to do `homestead.test:3000`?